# Why is a specific table becoming un-deletable sporadically?

Tags: sql-server, error-handling, timeout, drop-table

This is the error that i am getting: -

### TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Drop failed for Table 'dbo.FIST5$'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=14.0.17119.0+((SSMS_Rel).170517-0412)&EvtSrc=Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExceptionTemplates.FailedOperationExceptionText&EvtID=Drop+Table&LinkId=20476

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)

---

Lock request time out period exceeded. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 1222)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&ProdVer=13.00.4206&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=1222&LinkId=20476

---

BUTTONS:

### OK

Comment: You are trying to drop a table that is in use by another connection.

Comment: and that connection can be from R as well? RODBC?

Comment: Yes could be. There are plenty of queries on the web that will show you details of blocking queries that you can run next time the issue  happens (before the timeout actually occurs)